# Page cache doesn't work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have an action which needs to be cached:

```
caches_page :index

def index
  @boards = Board.all
  @boards.shuffle!

  render :layout => false 
end
```

Really simple. But the problem is, it's not really be cached. Every time I access `/boards`, Rails re-renders the action. How can I find what's wrong?

I don't change any config in `development.rb`.

Comment: "*I don't change any config in development.rb.*". That is your problem. Caching is explicitly disabled in development.rb. Please read the contents of that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Rails not writing the cached page?  Or not reading the cached page? (To see if it's writing the cached page, look in your public directory.)

You do need to set

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

in your development.rb file.  From your comment about *not* changing your configs, it sounds like that might be your problem.